# list packages installed from GitHub repository with their URL

Tags: r, git, github

I was trying to install Git on Windows 11 which gives me troubles with RStudio (no git tab despite projects set up for version control).
I want to try to reinstall Rstudio but I do not want to lose all the packages I've installed over the years.

I saved a list of my installed packages that I will then use to reinstall packages.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ip = as.data.frame(installed.packages()[,])
list_packages <- ip %>% select(., Package, LibPath, Version, Built)
save(list_packages, file = "save_list_packages.RData")
```

It should work for CRAN packages but not for GitHub packages.
**Is there a way to list which packages are coming from GitHub along with their repo URLs?**
I tried to locate a package in GitHub from its name but it is hard to find as repos can have the same name (i.e. identified by their URL that includes username and repo name).

**How do you do it in practise? Do you keep a script with all the GitHub package installations?**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the function `github_update()` from the `dtupdate` package:

```r
library(dtupdate)
list_gh <- github_update(auto.install = F)
#> Warning in read.dcf(url_con, fields = "Version"): cannot open URL 'https://
#> raw.githubusercontent.com/achetverikov/apastats/master/DESCRIPTION': HTTP status
#> was '404 Not Found'
#> Warning in read.dcf(url_con, fields = "Version"): cannot open URL 'https://
#> raw.githubusercontent.com/florianhartig/BayesianTools/master/DESCRIPTION': HTTP
#> status was '404 Not Found'
#> Warning in read.dcf(url_con, fields = "Version"): cannot open URL 'https://
#> raw.githubusercontent.com/jorvlan/raincloudplots/master/DESCRIPTION': HTTP
#> status was '404 Not Found'
head(list_gh)
#>         package       date version gh_version *
#> 1       adventr 2021-08-10  0.1.10     0.1.10  
#> 2        anicon 2021-11-20   0.1.0      0.1.0  
#> 3      apastats 2022-03-24     0.3       <NA>  
#> 4 BayesianTools 2021-06-14   0.1.7       <NA>  
#> 5        bbplot 2020-06-09     0.2        0.2  
#> 6     beautifyR 2022-01-10   0.3.1      0.3.2 *
#>                                         source
#> 1       Github (profandyfield/adventr@2d894ca)
#> 2            Github (emitanaka/anicon@0b756df)
#> 3       Github (achetverikov/apastats@448bb21)
#> 4 Github (florianhartig/BayesianTools@3f306aa)
#> 5                  Github (bbc/bbplot@82af595)
#> 6              Github (mwip/beautifyR@331a2cc)
```

The column `source` will show the user and the repo...

And, by the way... if you want to install all github packages from the respective user/repo:

```r
library(rex)
#extract only the "user/name" from the list_gh$source column
matches <- re_matches(list_gh$source,
                      rex(
                        "(",
                        capture(name = "text", except_any_of(")")),
                        "@"),
                      global = TRUE)
#add it as a column to the list_gh data frame (you do not really need this step) but to keep it more organized...
list_gh$user_repo <- matches |> bind_rows()

#install all github packages using pacman
pacman::p_install_gh(list_gh$user_repo)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>